# Does RDS Aurora has MySQL Events

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

We creates events in MySQL to perform certain jobs every weeks or at certain intervals like truncating weekly data

Does Aurora DB has the same functionality?

What does one normally use in Aurora to perform the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the parameter `event_scheduler` is present in the default Aurora parameter group.

[image]

It may not be enabled by default, so you'll have to enable it in your db parameter group.

Comment: Strange @BillKarwin, when I check the same default.aurora5.6 in my Parameter Groups, I do not see the event_scheduler parameter!

Comment: OK, I was looking at the Cluster Parameter Group! Thanks @BillKarmin!